# libvorbis.so error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have a next error when  do make on zaz game on a linux mint 17.1 (Rebecca) with a drivers  NVIDIA G98 GeForce 8400

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/miguel/tmp/zaz-1.0.0'
Making all in po
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/miguel/tmp/zaz-1.0.0/po'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/miguel/tmp/zaz-1.0.0/po'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/miguel/tmp/zaz-1.0.0/src'
g++  -g -O2   -o zaz main.o audiobuffer.o mixer.o oggsample.o scene.o settings.o wavesample.o streamingoggsample.o frame_events.o ogvexport.o bezier.o textureloader.o player.o level.o ballpath.o game.o editor.o mainmenu.o menu.o gameloop.o hiscores.o lineeditor.o tests.o profile.o directorylister.o levelset.o splash.o -lSDL -lvorbisfile -ltheoraenc -ltheoradec -logg   -lftgl     -lGL -lvorbisenc -lSDL_image 
/usr/bin/ld: ogvexport.o: undefined reference to symbol 'vorbis_bitrate_addblock'
//usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [zaz] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/miguel/tmp/zaz-1.0.0/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/miguel/tmp/zaz-1.0.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2

I Have installed lib vorbis

libvorbis-dbg:i386                              install
libvorbis-dev:i386                              install
libvorbis-ocaml                                 install
libvorbis-ocaml-dev                             install
libvorbis0a:i386                                install
libvorbisenc2:i386                              install
libvorbisfile3:i386                             install
libvorbisidec1                                  install
```

With other computer like same features not have a same problem, but the other computer don't have a nvidia card.

Thank for your help.

Comment: See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=768718

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tanks, I have resolv the problem change Makefile.ini after read this page:

https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1278320.html